# How to sort the files which are returned by findStr command, by modify date?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Currently, I need to find out all the files which contains the key word. Here is the command I am using `findstr /s /i "my-key-word" *.*`.

How can I sort the returned files by its modify date? Thanks.

Comment: Unless this is homework or something, please stay away from batch scripting for such tasks. In 2023 there are way better options, such as mentioned PowerShell. No reason to spend hour(s) of figuring out how to parse things with the outdated syntax. 2 minutes and task done with help of better tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier using PowerShell and searching in the
current folder:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-String "keyword" -List | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select Filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular **opinion**, this is rather easy to do in batch - however, it may be significantly slower.
Use `Dir` to sort the files first, and findstr to search the sorted files.

```
@For /f "delims=" %%G in ('Dir /b *.* /O:-D')Do @Findstr /li "searchstring" "%%G" > nul && Echo(%G
```

To search subfolders as well:

```
@For /f "delims=" %%G in ('Dir /b /s *.* /O:-D')Do @Findstr /li "searchstring" "%%G" > nul && Echo(%G
```

To sort as oldest first, change: `/O:-D` to `/O:D`

The above is the *simple* solution.
Performance wise, you could get a list of the files first using findstr, then begin assesing and sorting that list.